# Magento paypal is not working with not sported Currencies

Tags: paypal, multicurrency

I am using magento 1.9.2.4 and base currency of my website is SAR saudi riyal and I want to integrate paypal in my website but it shows this error PayPal gateway has rejected request.

Currency is not supported `(#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).`

I am using this extension >> https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento but after installing this extension also I'm getting the same issue can you please help me out with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the list of supported currencies by PayPal https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/, there NO `SAR` currency code.